# why the google chrome extension option page did not show alert message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a google chrome extension right now, In the google chrome extension UI page, I define a link like this in `template.html`:

```
<a href="#" @click="clearToken()">click</a>
```

when click the link in the UI, invoke the background method `clearToken`, this is the background code looks like:

```
import chromeCall from 'chrome-call';
import getOptions from '../../public/default-options';
import template from './template.html';

export default {
  template ,
  data : ()=> ({
    clearSuccess : false,
    options : {
      excludeDomains: []
    } ,
    showAdd : false ,
    tmpDomain : '',
    reddwarfUserName: '',
    reddwarfPassword: '',
    showYDApi : false,
    addYouDaoAPI : {
      apiKey : '',
      keyFrom : ''
    }
  }) ,
  methods : {
    clearToken() {
     alert("click");
  }
}})}
```

but when I click the link in the UI, did not alert any message, I am sure the background method was triggered because when I write a clear local storage key logic in the method and it works. why the background method did not show the alert information? what should I  do to debug the google chrome extension option page? I also tried to add `debugger` code in the background method, still did not trigger the breakpoint. I already opened the background page of the extension(but I could not open the popup page and option page in the same time). My google chrome version is `Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (arm64)`.

Comment: Chrome extensions cannot use inline Javascript. Attach the `onclick` event listener in a separate JS file.

Comment: Could you give a simple example? I already put the click method in  seperate file right now.@IvánNokonoko

Comment: 1) You need to configure Vue to compile the template during build. Otherwise there will be a CSP error in devtools console. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. 2) `alert` doesn't exist in a ManifestV3 background service worker.